# How to print paths using Haskell Turtle library?

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

To learn a bit about `Turtle`, I thought it would be nice to modify example from the tutorial. I chose to remove the reduntant "FilePath" from each line of the output thinking it would be a simple exercise.

And yet, despite author's efforts into making his library easy to use I nearly failed to use it to solve this simple problem.

I tried everyting I saw that looked like it would allow me to somehow lift `>>=` from `IO` into `Shell`: `MonadIO`, `FoldM`, `liftIO`, `_foldIO` with no success. I grew frustrated and only through reading `Turtle` source code I was able to find something that seems to work ("no obvious defects" comes to mind).

Why is this so hard? How does one logically arrive a solution using API of this library?

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-8.17 --install-ghc runghc --package turtle --package lens
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Turtle
import Control.Lens
import Control.Foldl as Foldl
import Filesystem.Path.CurrentOS
import Data.Text.IO as T
import Data.Text as T

main = do
  homedir <- home
  let paths = lstree $ homedir </> "projects"
  let t = fmap (Control.Lens.view _Right . toText) paths
  customView t

customView s = sh (do
  x <- s
  liftIO $ T.putStrLn x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't lift `>>=` from `IO` into `Shell`. `Shell` already has a `Monad` instance that comes with its own `>>=` function. Instead you either lift `IO` actions into `Shell` with `liftIO` or run the shell with [`fold`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.3.6/docs/Turtle-Shell.html#v:fold) or `foldM`. Use `sh` to run the `Shell` when you don't care about the results.

I believe your example can be simplified to

```
main = sh $ do
  homedir <- home
  filepath <- lstree $ homedir </> "projects"
  case (toText filepath) of
    Right path -> liftIO $ T.putStrLn x
    Left approx -> return () -- This shouldn't happen
```

As for the difficulty with getting a string back from a `FilePath`, I don't think that can be blamed on the Turtle author. I think it can be simplified to

```
stringPath :: FilePath -> String
stringPath filepath =
  case (toText filePath) of              -- try to use the human readable version
     Right path -> T.unpack path 
     Left _     -> encodeString filePath -- fall back on the machine readable one
```

Combined this would simplify the example to

```
main = sh $ do
  homedir <- home
  filepath <- lstree $ homedir </> "projects"
  liftIO $ putStrLn (stringPath filepath)
```

or

```
main = view $ do
  homedir <- home
  filepath <- lstree $ homedir </> "projects"
  return $ stringPath filepath
```